# Why is my type marked as shadowed name

Tags: typescript

In our typescript code, we have somewhere a shadowed name lint error. But I don't really get why this is shadowed in this particular case.

```
export class MockStore<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {
  constructor(private _initialState: T) {
    super(_initialState);
  }

  public dispatch = jest.fn();

  public select = <T, R>(pathOrMapFn: any, ...paths: string[]): Observable<R> => {
            HERE --^

    return map.call(this, pathOrMapFn);
  }
}
```

The `T` in my type definition is marked as shadowed name. I don't understand exactly why. In don't catch the "shadow variable" thing.

Comment: Because T is already defined as the generic type of the class. It's not clear why you put it in the method definition, which doesn't depend on T anyway, but as in the constructor you don't repeat the class generic type in the method to access it.

Comment: Thanks I get it. I thought I had to use the mail class type in any of my methods within that particular class. Generic type is new to me.

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html for more information